# Can I Install Old Packages on Newer Version of Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 yesterday. I want to know whether I can install the packages I downloaded previously, on this version of Ubuntu. Will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get the same settings on each package automatically, but you should be able to install the same packages themselves again from where you got them from.

You may have some problems as this is a newer, rawer version of Ubuntu. If you do, post them here and also press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` and type in `ubuntu-bug packagename` (replacing packagename with the name of the package), this will bug report them with log files.

Comment: I tried installing some previous packages (VLC Media Player, Ubuntu Tweak....), and Ubuntu stopped booting :( I had to re-install.

Comment: Stopped booting? Did you try pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` to get to a login terminal? If you do that if it happens again, I recommend doing the same process as mentioned before except filing it under package `lightdm`. You could also try switching to the [proprietary drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto) (I've had problems before that lead to the system gradually getting more unusable over time so I've switched to Ubuntu LTS).

And you can browse the Internet in the login terminal with Lynx. (Just type `lynx` in and press the `Enter` key.)

Comment: If the above doesn't work, just install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. It's a year older and has had more bug fixes/is more stable (because it's on older packages that are in support).